# SP2013 Display List Descripton

Tags: 2013, list-view

In Sp2007, if there is a description for List or Library, it will display on the view by default. My users used to use it as a instruction on how to use the list.

Now in SP2013 the description is hidden in the (i) icon callout next to the list title. Anyway I can display the Description on the View ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

While this is a dorky way to do it, it works as a quick-fix.

This will hide the description icon, pass the list description value to a variable and then print it below the list title.

Add an add a script editor webpart above the actual list and add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Get the description text.
var listDescription = document.getElementById("ms-pageDescription").innerHTML;
//Prints the description text.
document.write(listDescription);
</script>
<!--Hide the description icon.-->
<style type="text/css">
#ms-pageDescriptionImage {
display:none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS to display the description.

Just add this to your custom CSS file or as a style block in the MasterPage.

```
<style type="text/css">
span#ms-pageDescription {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    top: auto;
    /*Make it not an H1*/
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}
</style>
```